# How to change Time Zone in Alpha Vantage API

Tags: timezone, alpha-vantage

Can I change the time zone in the result from Alpha Vantage API? Here is an example of the output. It's currently in EST. I'd like to get it in IST.

```
'Meta Data': {
    '1. Information': 'Intraday (1min) open, high, low, close prices and volume',
    '2. Symbol': 'BSE:------',
    '3. Last Refreshed': '2019-11-01',
    '4. Output Size': 'Compact',
    '5. Time Zone': 'US/Eastern
}

'Time Series (1min)': {
    '2019-11-01 00:08:59': {
      '1. open': '70.7500',
      '2. high': '70.7500',
      '3. low': '70.7500',
      '4. close': '70.7500',
      '5. volume': '0'
    },
```

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

Right now the time zone that is returned is the only time zone you will receive from the API. However, if you're pulling the data in with a python script. You can always convert it to your time zone of choice.

```py
from alpha_vantage.timeseries import TimeSeries
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

ts = TimeSeries()

data, meta_data = ts.get_daily('TSLA')
format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

datetime = datetime.strptime(meta_data['3. Last Refreshed'], format)
old_timezone = pytz.timezone(meta_data['5. Time Zone'])
new_timezone = pytz.timezone("Asia/Calcutta")

# returns datetime in the new timezone
my_timestamp_in_new_timezone = old_timezone.localize(datetime).astimezone(new_timezone) 
print(my_timestamp_in_new_timezone.strftime(format))
```

You could run a method that just converts all the times to whatever timezone you want when you pull the data

Comment: you import in python package i need to change timeseries in node js

Comment: Check out this thread that answers the question but for javascript: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087819/convert-date-to-another-timezone-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

`ts.get_daily('TSLA')` should be changed to `ts.get_intraday('TSLA')`.